# How can i solve Foreign key mismatch error in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to connect the two tables in django but i am getting the error

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: foreign key mismatch - "website_doctor" referencing "website_field"

please suggest a way to solve it

[image: Here is my code]

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Comment: You probably created a model named `Field`, deleted it, then created the model `Fields`.  Find the migration file that has `Field` model, delete it, then run makemigrations again.  The migrations file is in the migrations folder (the file is automatically generated whenever you run makemigrations).

Comment: did you made any changes in your models and did you tried to make migrations?